# How can i stop EC2 instance automatically after launching , based on specified hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i know how to launch and how to stop ec2 instance using Ruby sdk.now i need automatically shutdown based on hour parameter, after launching ec2 instance ?
how can i solve this problem? please provide some useful reference.

```
   #disconnecting EC2 Instance 
   def disconnect_group_instance
        if current_user.present?
          server_instance = GroupUserInstance.find_by_group_user_id(params[:id])
           ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
           resp = ec2.stop_instances({
           dry_run: false,
           instance_ids: [server_instance.server_id],
           force: false
         })
       end
   end
```

is there any way to pass time variable and based on that i can perform appropriate action?

Comment: I don't really understand your request, but is this something that could be solved by lambda? Just shutdown the server every hour?

Comment: thank you @George Appleton for your response. actually i am looking for api call, because my time period is user defined.(it may be 200 hour, 300hour and so on) . based on time period over, i need to shut down ec2 instnace automatically.

Comment: aws api should be able to handle that easily 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/stop-instances.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_StopInstances.html there are two links which should help. You should be able to get the instance to shut down itself. But an alternative if you have issues is to get a lambda endpoint to query your ec2 instance api every x time period and on certain responses shutdown the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import json
import boto3

#python script to turn off the list of vms using lambda on daily/hourly basis

'''
event = {
 "topic_arn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:aws-account_id:sns_topic",
 "instance_id": "i-0fbaf00d222f6f765",
 "action": "stop",
 "region": "ap-southeast-1"
}
'''

#arguments can be passed through cloudwatch event which triggers lambda function or through lambda environment variables

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
 topic_arn = event['topic_arn']
 instance_id = event['instance_id']
 action = event['action']
 region = event['region']

 subject = instance_id
 ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
 sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
 message = { "topic_arn" : topic_arn, "instance" : instance_id }
 
 def stop_instance(instance_id):
  stop_instance = ec2_client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id,],Force=True)
  message['status'] = 'stopped'
  send_notification(topic_arn, subject, message)
  return message
 def start_instance(instance_id):
  start_instance = ec2_client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id,])
  message['status'] = 'started'
  send_notification(topic_arn, subject, message)
  return message
 def send_notification(topic_arn, subject, message):
  publish = sns_client.publish(   TopicArn=topic_arn, \
             Message=json.dumps(message), \
             Subject=subject \
            )
 if action == 'stop':
  return(stop_instance(instance_id))
  
 else:
     return(start_instance(instance_id))
```

Comment: i need api call using ruby sdk ,like i mentioned above  in my question. i don't want to use lambda function for this. is there any way ,if api is not available ?

Comment: Ideally you need a job scheduler or event driven source to accomplish this action. If you do not find any api. You can schedule a cron job to poll the uptime of the vm thru bash/ruby/python script every day at 12:00am hour. If it reaches the desired hour you can execute halt/init 0 command to stop the vm by itself.

Comment: @NeerajAmoli lambda does support ruby by the way